# Print all translations of a column in same Rails Show Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slug, rails-i18n

I'm trying to do a weird thing:

In a web with I18n I pretend to print the slug of current page.

```
ModelName.friendly.find(params[:id]).slug.to_s
```

It works, it renders not only the slug but any column I want.

But I need to print also the slug of each language in the same page.
What I pretend is to repeat 3 times that line of code, how can I set different locale for each line? in order to to get something like this:

- Native slug
- Native translated slug 1
- Native translated slug 2

Answer (score 0):

I18n supports different ways of setting the used locale for a certain call to the translate method.

This requires you to have set up a locale file, e.g. in config/locales/fr.yml for French:

```
fr:
  websites:
    slug: "ma-traduction-de-slug"
```

And similarly for all other desired languages.

**I18n.with_locale(locale_identifier)**

```
I18n.with_locale(:en) do
  I18n.t("websites.slug")
end
```

**Pass locale in the call to I18n.t**

```
I18n.t("websites.slug", locale: :fr)
```

An implementation could look like this:

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  puts I18n.t("websites.slug", locale: locale)
end
```

If you're looking for translations in the used routes and paths of your application like:

```
/models/mon-traduction-de-slug
```

have a look at https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator

And finally if you want to [manage locale files online](https://phraseapp.com), we provide a tool for this. Free for open source projects: [PhraseApp](https://phraseapp.com)